# AWS Step Function Retry creates a job with the same name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I created a Step in my step function which has a [Retrier](https://aws-step-functions-data-science-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/states.html#stepfunctions.steps.states.State.add_retry). It works as intended, but every time it tries to re-run my failed step it creates a new job with the same name as the first one, leading to the "Job name must be unique within an AWS account and region, and a job with this name already exists" error.
What can I do? as of now the retrier is useless.

Comment: can you provide a snippet of how your sfn.Task is defined?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/8zgfijDQ

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your step function to define the training job name:

`"TrainingJobName.$": "States.Format('{}-{}-{}', $$.StateMachine.Name, $$.Execution.Name, $$.State.RetryCount)"`

This will name the training job based on the name of your state machine + the unique id of the execution + the number of retries.
Therefore the name will be unique even when retrying using the Retrier.

When using the Data Science SDK, I did not find I direct way to set the job_name parameter to this, but you can override it like this:

```
training_step = steps.TrainingStep(
    "Train Step",
    estimator=xgb,
    data={
        "train": sagemaker.TrainingInput(train_s3_file, content_type="application/x-parquet"),
        "validation": sagemaker.TrainingInput(validation_s3_file, content_type="application/x-parquet"),
    },
    job_name=ExecutionInput()["dummy"],
    parameters = {
        "TrainingJobName.$": "States.Format('{}-{}-{}', $$.StateMachine.Name, $$.Execution.Name, $$.State.RetryCount)",
    },
    retry=default_retryer,
)
```

See that I set the job_name to `ExecutionInput()["dummy"]`, but then use the parameters to override it.
Be careful that the name of the job does not contain any illegal characters or becomes too long. State Machine and Sagemaker Jobs have different Naming requirements.